# Suspicious behaviour - str not callable in return "".join(list(map(str,reversed(result)))) in Python 3.4.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is return statement from one of my functions

```
return "".join(list(map(str,reversed(result))))
```

that raises exception

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I checked all stackoverflow answers for raised TypeError but nothing helps. If I try to inject simple code like

```
print(type(str(1000)))
```

immediately before return statement then that print executes OK. I haven't created variable 'str'. I have no idea what's wrong.

P.S.: result is list of integers. I'm using CPython 3.4.1

Comment: Did you name one of your variables the same as any of those functions? `list`, `map`, `reversed`, etc?

Comment: Did you assign anything to `str` before this?

Comment: Can you post an example input, and what your desired output is?

Comment: @Cyber you are right. After trying to come up wit MCVE I found out that map has been assigned a string value. That's why the **str error**. I focused all my attention to __str__ in that code and didn't realize that map (now as a instance of str) is what's not callable. I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

Using CPython 3.4.2 on Win 7, your line works fine (copied and pasted).

```
>>> result = [1,2,3]
>>> "".join(list(map(str,reversed(result))))
'321'
```

Deleting the unnecessary `list(...)` call works as well.

```
>>> "".join(map(str,reversed(result)))
'321'
```

What is a [minimal *complete* verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (that any of us can run *as is* in a fresh interpreter) that demonstrates the problem for you?